# How to initialize django objects automatically for the first time?

Tags: python, django

This is my first django application and I looked all over the place to find an answer, to no avail.

I created my models and I know need to to initialize the values to one of the classes. I could do it using the admin page, one by one, but I want anyone using my application to be able to just load the application for the first time to have all the correct objects (and associated records in the database) to be created automatically.

Please help

Comment: After creating your models, did you run `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Can you explain better? Do you mean for example using JSON or inside the web through forms?

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to populate database check the wiki for [initial data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/). You can use JSON, XML or YAML (with PyYAML installed). I think you are looking for this as your question is not that clear.

Comment: After I asked the question I stumbled upon the page you referenced and I did just that. I will actually create a way to create a YAML formatted file off a CSV file that my users can provide from say Excel.