# ModelChoiceField does not show ForeignKey choices

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to show a dropdown in Django Form where the dropdown items are specified in another model in another app. Here's what I mean:

**title/models.py**

```
TITLE_CHOICES = (
    ('MR', 'Mr'),
    ('MS', 'Ms'),
    ('MISS', 'Miss'),
    ('MRS', 'Mrs'),
    ('MX', 'Mx'),
)

class Title(models.Model):
    title_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title_name
```

**user/models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    user_title = models.ForeignKey('title.Title', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

**user/forms.py**

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
        user_title = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Title.objects.all())

        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = '__all__'

        def signup(self, request, user): #this is to override the **allauth** signup form
            user.user_title = self.cleaned_data['title_name']
            ...
            ...

            user.save()
```

With the above code, the dropdown field renders properly; however, it is empty.
[image]

Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't use `user_title=models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)` in User class instead?

Comment: @riNg, I want to keep the titles in a separate app, so that it can easily be used in other applications in my Django project.

Comment: If that so, you have to create titles before creating user. It's empty because you didn't have any titles in your database.

Comment: @riNg is there a way to automatically populate the database with the title choices? Imagine having 100s of choices, surely there's a more productive way of adding these choices to the database than doing it manually?

Comment: If you don't need to add/change/delete titles, then you don't need Title Model. Else, if you have a decent of default titles and want to auto-create them, maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46761148/how-to-initialize-django-objects-automatically-for-the-first-time

Comment: Do you have any **`Title`** instances in your database?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, when I add Title instances in the database, there are two problems: 1) the dropdown displays the actual name of the choice, not the human-readable name. 2) If a model field has 1000s of choices (e.g., name of cities) then adding each one in the database is inefficient. I'm new to Django, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I got the first case. In Django, this is how it will be, ***by default***. Regarding the second, I don't understand your ***use-case***. If the choices to be the name of cities, you have to add the values/data to database ***"somehow and once"***

Answer (score 5):

Please change your user_title field to this and Try this.

```
user_title = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Title.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to create all of the choices in TITLE_CHOICES you declared, I would just make a fixture and load it to database.

I would change the model a bit: `title.models`

```
def Title(models.Model):
    title_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title_name
```

then make a json file: `title/fixtures/titles.json`

```
[
    {
        "model": "title.Title",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
          "title_name": "MR",
          "title" : "Mr"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "title.Title",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
          "title_name": "MS",
          "title" : "Ms"
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

Then load this json file to database by `python manage.py loaddata titles` command. This will automatically create all instances in json file to database.

Note that you have to save the file in a folder named `fixtures` otherwise it returns error.

Now while creating the user you will get the Title `ForeignKey` will show the `title_name` in options list instead of the `title`.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_title = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Title.objects.all(), flat=True)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.